# OAuth2 grant-type for my web app API

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools

I am working on an API for my web application that can provide raw JSON data for my users in to use as they wish. I am using Apigility which comes with an OAuth2 implementation.

I'd like my users to visit a screen in my app to get their assigned credentials, then use them to consume the API. Do I need to create a client_id for each user or can they all share the same client and use different usernames/passwords?

I'm also not sure which oauth grant-type would be the most applicable. Because no third-party is involved, it seems the 'password' grant-type might be sufficient; but I still have to provide the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' in the headers of the request?

What is the best way to provide credentials and to authenticate users on a RESTful API when they will only be consuming it themselves?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant for the reasons you mention. Your app would only need a single `client_id` and `client_secret` to handle different users/passwords.

You would provide those values (`client_id`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password`) as part of the HTTP POST parameters of the request to the token endpoint and get back an access token that you would use in the headers against the API.

Comment: Thank you! I read that if you leave the client_secret blank in the db, you do not need to provide it to get an access token. What are the benefits/drawbacks of this?

Comment: benefit is one secret less to maintain, drawback is that you don't control the client/app instances anymore that use your infrastructure to check username/passwords; anyone could cook up a client and start accessing your token server and API and you have no means to stop it (the client_id is not a real secret)